Не работают видео в тикток и на сайтах с фильмами PyQT6
Я пытаюсь написать на pyqt миниокно с возможностью смотреть тикток, ютуб и фильмы. Проблема в том, что видео в тикток вообще не грузят (при использовании библиотеки webview все грузит) а на сайтах с фильмами просто не дает нажать кнопку запуска видео. Что нужно сделать чтобы исправить это ?
П.с. Ютуб работает корректно.
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineProfile
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon

class MobileWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, profile):
        super().__init__(profile)
        self.profile().setHttpUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1")

class SocialMediaApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Социальные сети')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 350, 500)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        profile = QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView()
        self.web_page = MobileWebEnginePage(profile)
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.web_view)

        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        youtube_button = QPushButton('', self)
        youtube_button.setIcon(QIcon('youtube_icon.png'))
        youtube_button.clicked.connect(self.open_youtube)
        youtube_button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
        button_layout.addWidget(youtube_button)

        vk_shorts_button = QPushButton('', self)
        vk_shorts_button.setIcon(QIcon('vk_icon.png'))
        vk_shorts_button.clicked.connect(self.open_vk)
        vk_shorts_button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
        button_layout.addWidget(vk_shorts_button)

        google_button = QPushButton('', self)
        google_button.setIcon(QIcon('google_icon.png'))
        google_button.clicked.connect(self.open_google)
        google_button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
        button_layout.addWidget(google_button)

        main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def open_youtube(self):
        self.web_view.load(QUrl('https://m.youtube.com'))

    def open_vk(self):
        self.web_view.load(QUrl('https://vk.com/video/'))

    def open_google(self):
        self.web_view.load(QUrl('https://www.google.com/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SocialMediaApp()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

